# Jquery .on() Event Firing Multiple Times on same Class Elements even on using .off()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating onthefly grid layout, where a class will get attached to clicked class's element and some manual text from input field will be inserted in that element.

When I click on element, it gets activated and html is passed to that element but on clicking second element, .on() fires multiple times and all elements gets the same html data instead of separate data.

**I have tried .off() and .stopPropagation() etc.**[image]

```
function changeModal (object) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModalLabel').text('Enter Seat Number');
    $('.addSeatNumber').click(function () {
        var seatNumber = $('#seatNumberHolder').val();
        $(object).addClass('activated').attr('data-seatNumber',seatNumber).text(seatNumber);
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
}
function pushSeat (object) {
    var object = '#'+object.attr('id');
    if($(object).hasClass('activated')) {
        $(object).removeClass('activated').html('');
    }
    else {
        changeModal(object);
    }
};
$(document).on('click', '.seat',function(e) {
        var id = $(this);
        e.stopPropagation();
        pushSeat(id);
});


function CreateTheatre () {
    this.rows = 20, this.columns = 10;
    this.seatRowName  = function (a) {
        return String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    }
    this.render = function () {
        var layout = '';
        var seatRowStart = 'A';
        for (var i = 0; i < this.columns; i++) {
            layout += '<div class="seatRow">'+seatRowStart+'</div>';
            if (seatRowStart == 'Z') {
                seatRowStart = '`';
            }
            seatRowStart = this.seatRowName(seatRowStart);
            for (var j = 0; j < this.rows; j++) {
                layout += '<div id="'+seatRowStart+(j+1)+'" class="seat"></div>';
            }
            layout += '<div class="clear"></div>';
        }
        $('.seatContainer').html(layout);
    };
};
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: `$('.addSeatNumber').click(function () {` adds a click a handler for each element in the collection. Execute it 10 times and you will have 10 click handlers for each element ;)

Comment: I have updated the HTML onthefly creating **Class CreateTheatre()**

Comment: I solved this problem. Thank you for your answers. Specially @vohuman . Thanks for your hint.

Comment: you can use `live` or `on` event in place of click for the hint given by @Vohuman

Answer (score 0):

**I moved my $('.addSeatNumber').click(function(){ out from Modal Box and used global variable to store final element id.**

```
var myHack;
function changeModal (object) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModalLabel').text('Enter Seat Number');
    myHack = object;
}
function pushSeat (object) {
    var object = '#'+object.attr('id');
    if($(object).hasClass('activated')) {
        $(object).removeClass('activated').html('');
    }
    else {
        changeModal(object);
    }
};


$(document).on('click', '.seat',function(e) {
        var id = $(this);
        e.stopPropagation();
        pushSeat(id);
});
$('#addTheatre').click(function () {
    saveTheatre();
})
$('.addSeatNumber').click(function () {
    var seatNumber = $('#seatNumberHolder').val();
    $(myHack).addClass('activated').attr('data-seatNumber',seatNumber).text(seatNumber);
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```